# Error: No controller: ngModel

Tags: javascript, web-applications, angularjs, angularjs-scope

When I add `ng-change="reverseOrder=this.checked"` to a checkbox, as so:

```
<input id="reverseOrder" type="checkbox" ng-change="reverseOrder=this.checked"/>
```

I get the following exception:

```
Error: No controller: ngModel
```

I've tried adding `ng-model` to the inputbox, a div wrapping the entire view and in the `<html>` tag, this produces an exception liek the following:

```
Error: Non-assignable model expression:  (<div class="ng-scope" ng-model="">)
```

What's going on here?  I didn't think I needed to explicitly pull in the model.  I've read the [Angular documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel) but am none the wiser.

Thanks in advance.

Dave

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ngChange` requires `ngModel` directive. But you're using `ngChange` for the same purpose of `ngModel`. Just go with:

```html
<input id="reverseOrder" type="checkbox" ng-model="reverseOrder"/>
```